# CONTEST: optimize size of grayscale scanned documents!

Tags: optimization, image-processing, compression, photoshop

I put this as a contest, but it's still a question!

Here's the original image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1663633/original_scan.jpg

Original size is about 1 megabyte. How would you reduce the size so that the final print on a A4 paper (about letter size I think..) still looks good?

Rules:

- The process MUST be automatic (to be applied to hundreds of similar images) therefore no manual correction is allowed (like erase black borders in photoshop with the eraser tool)
- Resolution (200dpi) cannot be lowered any further

Here are a few Ideas

- reduce number of colors
- reduce noise (black pixels without any meaning..) and smooth things out..

I managed to achieve 156KB, can you best me? You should explain how you did it of course =)

P.S. I uploaded my image with dropbox but maybe there's a simpler way.. don't know..
you can look at my compressed version [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1663633/compressed.png)

Comment: I wanted to give the winner some 75 reputation, but I thinks I have to wait for the bounty option to appear..

Comment: Looks more like that you want people to code for you than a contest to be fair.

Comment: I won by reducing the size to 1px by 1px. Only 1byte!

Comment: @Maurius, tried that. Assuming that the pixel has a solid color (most has) and no transparency, the best I got (with Paint.NET) was a tga-file of 22 bytes. What you have done is increased the image header to 86% of the data. Unacceptable! ;)

Comment: You should change the wording to grayscale, unless you are willing to accept the degraded results of a true b/w image. You could convert it to text via OCR and do gz compression.

Comment: @Sbm007: I'm not asking you to code for me! I already did it in photoshop with very good results. I wanted to know if someone had some better idea.
@stever: you're right, I meant grayscale. I for instance used 4 shades of gray in my processing.

Comment: Without a way to measure image quality or at least a standard location to put images for comparison this question isn't useful.

Comment: @tom10:  agreed.  This question is ill-posed, and needs a clearer set of criteria (like PSNR or somesuch).  My money goes on one of the newer compression algorithms, such as SPIHT (set partitioning in hierarchical trees... IIRC, basically a very clever combination of quadtrees and wavelets).

But without some win/lose incentive and clear rules, why compete?

Comment: Ok probably I didn't put this question in the right way. I'm sorry.
Close it if you can

Answer (score 1):

You can use ImageMagick to convert it to a G4 tiff:

```
convert original_scan.jpg -type bilevel -monochrome -compress group4 \
    -negate original_scan.tiff
```

72k on my machine. Zip that up and it's 66k.

Comment: not bad but a bit too B/W =)
I post my version so you can see